# JavaFX: Is there a best practice for a constructor replacement?

Tags: java, javafx

Everyone who's using JavaFX knows there is no constructor. The controllers are starting with the initialize-method.

My solution for passing things to the beginning was to create a method like `setupMyController(String example);`
The problem is, when another programmer changes the code he isn't forced to use this method so things which had to be passed to the controller could be null.

Does anybody know a way that can't avoid the setup?

Comment: What do you mean by `no constructor`? Every class has a constructor and it is true for JavaFX controllers as well.

Comment: ?? If you call a FXML over the FXML loader you get the controller from the loader by `loader.getController()`. Where do you call a constructor there?

Comment: The `FXMLLoader` calls the constructor for you. By default it calls the no-argument constructor, but you can change that behavior by setting a controller factory on the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: That seems to be the solution for the problem ;3 I'll check that soon. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DI container (eg. Guice) and custom controller factory